# How can I understand this code? Why it is returning 2 instead of 1?

Tags: swift

```
func randomInteger(integersArr: [Int?]?) -> Int {
    (integersArr?.randomElement() ?? 1) ?? 2
}

var nums: [Int?]? = [nil, nil]
let res = randomInteger(integersArr: nums)
print(res)
```

As the left side expression will return a nil, I was expecting it will return 1 bc of first null coalescing but it returns 2.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the array you pass are of type `Optional<Int>` where [Optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) is an enum with the items `some` and `none`.

Since the array does contain elements the are actually `Optional<Int>.some(nil)` so that is why the are not unwrapped to 1 but the wrapped value of the `some` is as mentioned nil so 2 is returned instead.

To get 1 back you need either to pass nil as the argument or an empty array so `randomElement()` returns nil

```
randomInteger(integersArr: nil) 
randomInteger(integersArr: [])
```

Here is another way to write your code

```
switch integersArr?.randomElement() {
case .some(let value):
    return value == nil ? 2 : value!
case .none:
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `randomInteger` coded in Swift accepts an optional array of optional integers, randomly selects an element in the provided array, then returns it.

- If either the array or the optional integer is nil, the function returns 1.
- If the resulting optional integer is still nil, the function returns 2.

The issue I'm seeing is you don't actually have a way to return 1 based on your current function. To illustrate the point better, I remade the function in JavaScript:

```js
function randomInteger(integersArr) {
  if (!integersArr) {
    return 2;
  }
  const filteredArr = integersArr.filter(element => element !== null && element !== undefined);
  if (filteredArr.length === 0) {
    return 2;
  }
  const randomElement = filteredArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredArr.length)];
  return (randomElement === null || randomElement === undefined) ? 2 : randomElement;
}
const nums = [null, null];
const res = randomInteger(nums);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It will return 1 if I set the nums array as nil.

var nums: [Int?]? = nil